# CSS white inner shadow

Tags: css

How can I make white inner shadow in the div?

I've trying with other colors — works fine, but with white color that don't work.

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/vekic/1/edit)

Thanks!

**Update**:
I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsbin.com/qudobipu/1/edit?html,css,output Are you sure you didn't have the background color set to white as well? White on white can't be seen...

Comment: looks like you need some inner content wrapper, http://jsbin.com/tiludaqu/1/ , the `box-shadow` seems to be put behind the content, there is no way to bring it to front unless using some inner content wrapper (as in the demo).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can create a simple overlay on the layer above the content and make it your box-shadow

```css
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
}

.container .content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.container:after {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 110px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #fff, transparent);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: close-quote;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro nesciunt quo fuga quasi vero modi aspernatur
            nemo harum sapiente nobis ex aliquam excepturi possimus sit laboriosam libero adipisci non aliquid.Lorem
            ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta libero modi debitis ipsa architecto nihil
            exercitationem cumque natus ducimus at quae doloribus illum optio aut expedita eveniet magnam officiis
            qui!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam officia reiciendis doloremque neque
            debitis aperiam voluptates non libero atque ut iure rem consequuntur alias commodi velit asperiores sit
            nesciunt minima. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos dolor ab animi ullam id
            incidunt tempore atque doloremque quidem quaerat soluta eaque expedita aspernatur velit reprehenderit
            doloribus similique. Quod non.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit delectus iste
            aliquid vero ut? Odio quas asperiores odit velit vitae aspernatur beatae! Adipisci molestias placeat maiores
            eos voluptatum assumenda sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci similique
            quos fugit nostrum neque sit repudiandae error laborum possimus voluptatum molestiae impedit quo repellendus
            minus corrupti doloribus itaque ipsa consequatur!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Consequuntur molestias odit numquam soluta veniam saepe incidunt dolore praesentium nobis labore amet cumque
            aliquam et consectetur est at quis voluptas doloremque?
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
box-shadow: grey 0px 30px 40px -2em inset;
```

Use grey into white.
If I understood well, you want a white shadow inside a white input? You need a different color to make the shadow.

I have maybe misunderstood, don't know. Tell me if this helped or if I just didn't understand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please look at the update question.

Comment: Ok, I will investigate. As soon as you find solution tell me to stop looking for it. Good luck!

Comment: Only managed to make the white show work changing the div background, or make a grey shadow. White shadow on top of white background div could not make it work.